# Update spaCy Vocabulary

Tags: python, word2vec, spacy

I was wondering if it is possible to update spacys default vocabulary. What I am trying doing is this:

- run word2vec on my own corpus with gensim
- load the vectors into my model with `nlp.vocab.load_vectors_from_bin_loc(\path)`

But since a lot of words in my corpus aren't in spacys default vocabulary I can't make use of the imported vectors. Is there an (easy) way to add those missing types?

**Edit:**
I realize it might be problematic to mix vectors. So my question is:
How can I import a custom vocabulary into spacy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is much easier in the next version, which should be out this week --- I'm just finishing testing it. For now:

By default spaCy loads a data/vocab/vec.bin file, where the "data" directory is within the spacy.en module directory
Create the vec.bin file from a bz2 file using spacy.vocab.write_binary_vectors
Either replace spaCy's vec.bin file, or call nlp.vocab.load_rep_vectors at run-time, with the path to the binary file.
The above is a bit inconvenient at first, but the binary file format is much smaller and faster to load, and the vectors files are fairly big. Note that GloVe distributes in gzip format, not bzip.

Out of interest: are you using the GloVe vectors, or something you trained on your own data? If your own data, did you use Gensim? I'd like to make this much easier, so I'd appreciate suggestions for what work-flow you'd like to see.

**Load new vectors at run-time, optionally converting them**

```
    import spacy.vocab

    def set_spacy_vectors(nlp, binary_loc, bz2_loc=None):
        if bz2_loc is not None:
            spacy.vocab.write_binary_vectors(bz2_loc, binary_loc)
        write_binary_vectors(bz2_input_loc, binary_loc)

        nlp.vocab.load_rep_vectors(binary_loc)
```

**Replace the vec.bin, so your vectors will be loaded by default**

```
from spacy.vocab import write_binary_vectors
    import spacy.en

    from os import path

    def main(bz2_loc):
        bin_loc = path.join(path.dirname(spacy.en.__file__), 'data', 'vocab', 'vec.bin')
        write_binary_vectors(bz2_loc, bin_loc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    plac.call(main)
```

Comment: It would be cool to easily dump the spacy.vocab vectors in a useable format by gensim, retrain with gensim on a new corpus and then reload in Spacy. Is this currently straightforward?